# Telegram image scraper

Tags: python, django, image, nginx, telegram

**Hi,** I have trouble with Telegram images scraper (I don't know how to call it). It's a feature that puts an image in chat via URL.
(Screenshot below).
[image: Telegram image scrapper]

But when I am trying to serv static files by Django or Flask Telegram really can't scrap that image.
(Screenshot below)

[image: Telegram scrapping]

Also, I've tried NGINX server but seems similar.

Did anybody know how that feature works or somebody tried to do that
on their own?  Maby I should register the domain?

Comment: HTML code in the web page that works and Django web page is similar.

Comment: sidenote - this should be called as a scraper. A Scaper scraps off data from a website. You need to paste an image into chat. A better name maybe?

Comment: If Telegram is not able to show the image, check if you are sending correct headers , like Content-Type ?